# Cursors running 100 times slower in SQL Server 2008 R2 than in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I am upgrading an application from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2, and running into timeout issues with stored procedures that use cursors. For instance, one SP that handled 500 rows per second in SQL Server 2000 is crawling along at 5 about rows per second (and 100% CPU) in SQL Server 2008. This is in a VM, but memory does not seem to be an issue.

I've tried resetting statistics, and rebuilding indices, with no effect. I can rewrite the SPs to avoid using cursors, but would prefer not to increase the scope to include those rewrites.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Here is a simple example of an SP that takes about 100 times as long after the upgrade. In my test on SQL Server 2008 R2, it takes 12 seconds to process 4000 rows.

```
--set ids by alphabetical order
declare cursor1 CURSOR
FOR

select id from form_import_current_data
where master_formulary_id = @Master_Formulary_ID
order by description, description2
open cursor1

declare @id int
declare @id_counter int
set @id_counter = 1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id

while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
    BEGIN
        update form_import_current_data
        set  id = @id_counter
        where master_formulary_id = @Master_Formulary_ID
          and id = @id

        set @id_counter = @id_counter + 1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id
END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

Comment: If you would avoid a cursor, it would run 1000x  **faster** than before...

Comment: Thanks. "I can rewrite the SPs to avoid using cursors, but would prefer not to increase the scope to include those rewrites."

Comment: (1) If you upgraded this database from 2000 -> 2008 R2, make sure you upgrade the compatibility level. (2) Change `DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR` to `DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR`. [Details](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options).

Comment: (3) Is the `ORDER BY` on the cursor declaration really important? It may be adding an unnecessary sort. (4) Make sure to always properly reference objects (e.g. `dbo.form_import_current_data`). (5) Really, really, really get rid of the cursor. "Increase the scope" is ridiculous when it would take a minute and a half to convert this to a single statement.

Comment: Get in a time machine........go back in time...........and punch in the guy the person who said "let's put cursors everywhere!"...............  You should rewrite the ones you can.  The above would be so simply rewritten..........it makes no sense not to, IMHO.

Comment: All right, all right, I give up! I'm rewriting the SPs. (And granadaCoder, I don't need the time machine because the guys who wrote this still work here.)

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the suggestions, I ended up doing some old trick and it worked miracles!

I had this cursor which was taking almost 3 mins to run, while the enclosing query was instant. I have other databases with more complex cursors that were only taking 1 second or less, so I ruled out the global issue on using cursors. My solution:

Detach the database in question, but ensure you tick Update Statistics.
Attach the database and check performance
This seems to help optimize all the performance parameters without the detailed effort. I am using SQL Express 2008 R2.

Would like to know your experience.